# How to let the user create a new directory but as a subdomain instead PHP?

Tags: php, directory, subdomain

```
<?php 

$dirPath = $_POST['username'];
$dirPass = $_POST['password'];

if (file_exists($dirPath)) {
    echo("Not available");
} else {

    if (isset($_REQUEST['sav']))
    {  
        header('Location: http://example.com/'.$dirPath);
    }

    $result = mkdir($dirPath, 0755);

    function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
        $dir = opendir($src); 
        @mkdir($dst); 
        while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) { 
            if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) { 
                if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) { 
                    recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
                } 
                else
                { 
                    copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
        closedir($dir); 
    }

    // Source directory (can be an FTP address)
    $src = "copy/";
    // Full path to the destination directory
    $dst = "$dirPath/";

    recurse_copy($src,$dst);
}
?>
```

Above shows the code that I am following. There is a form with an input field, when the user types something into that input and hits submit, a new directory will be created called 'Whatever he entered in the input' and it will contain all the files from an existing directory called 'Copy'.

This works perfectly. Lets say the user enters 'Example' and hits submit, he would have to go to http://example.com/Example.

How would I make it so that when the new directory is created, the user would have to go to a subdomain to access it. http://Example.example.com instead of http://example.com/Example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:
First configure your webserver that it routes all subdomain traffic to the same webspace. With apache you can do this with a wildcard virtual host entry. E.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/webroot/
</VirtualHost>
```

Second I would create a .htaccess rewrite condition that redirects subdomain requests to the matching folder.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1
```

I have not tested this, but I think it illustrates the concept.

Comment: I would probably use the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` over the webspace configuration, so that the code is more portable (i.e. nginx servers). Also it works on shared web hosting solutions.

Comment: @ricktap That would not solve the problem that all subdomain traffic needs to get routed to the same webspace. I think that only can be done with webserver specific techniques.

Comment: oh sorry, I was too unspecific. The wildcard stuff would need to be in place ofcourse, I was just meaning the htaccess file as it is not supported by all webservers. I would go a programmatic route instead of using rewrites. This way your codebase would not mess with the webserver in anyway, and would just serve pages from a subfolder based on requests